# When to use "fixed number of components" in a PCA

Tags: pca, psychometrics

The question is relatively simple (and stupid maybe). When do I use a fixed number of components (especially in analyzing a questionnaire). Is it useful when I have literature to a validated scale/questionnaire? And how do I interprete my results when I have already a fixed number of components.

Comment: PCA is computed by many functions in different packages, and it may help to know which function you are referring to for ```nFactorMethod = "fixed"```.

Comment: Apparently, your question refers to the function `pca` in the R package `jmc`. The documentation of this function does not explain what `nFactorMethod="fixed"` means. Can you please elaborate on the menaing of this parameter?

Comment: @ChristianHennig  I edited my question since the code isn't helpful at all. Basically I'd like to know when fixing components instead of using eigenvalue or parrarell analysis is useful. Like I want to reduce my data to 6 components.

Comment: @cdalitz nFactorMethod is used to determine the number of factors ('parallel' (default), 'eigen' or 'fixed', ). This package is from Jamovi that I have to use sometimes. I've never seen this in R so far. Fixed means that I choose the number of components that I want to keep.

Comment: Neither of the words "parallel" or "eigen" make any sense to me. One common method is to specify a percentage of the total variance, maybe this is meant with "eigen"? Using a fixed number of components is most useful for visualization purpose (so called "multi diemensainal scaling").

Comment: @cdalitz eigen means based on eigenvalue (K1). Parallel refers to parallel analysis. I actually don't try to understand the code it is just the method to fix the number of components to reduce the data to.

Comment: @cdalitz it seems the package is `jmv` rather than *jmc*.  But you are correct: setting `nFactorMethod="fixed", nFactors=2` should lead to precisely 2 components

Comment: @Henry But why would you want to use this?

Comment: @PeterSilie Perhaps you want to check the calculations of somebody who used two components, or plot a [two-dimensional graph of clusters](https://github.com/Henrygb/Clustering_Euroelections_in_R/blob/master/Clustering_Euroelections_in_R.md), or some other reason

Comment: @Henry Do you know what this is called? I can't find any literature or internet sites explaining this. Basically I could imagine that this is used to check dimensions from a model in scale. But I can't find any explanation on how to retain components if you proceed like this.

Comment: @Peter-Sille "Do you know how this is called?" PCA occurs in many different contexts and can be used for many different goals: Orthogonal Least Squares (only first component, i.e. largest eigen value), Multidimensional Scaling (first and second component), dimension reduction in feature space or feature extraction (eigenvalues that sum up to certain percentage). Choose any of the terms.